# How to use a different Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, tcp

I'm running a virtual machine at home which has a VPN connection to our main office, but I also want to connect to a share on another machine at home.

When I check with `IPCONFIG` I can see two ethernet connections ...

my work VPN ...

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 11:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxx
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

and home local ...

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxx
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.70
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

What's weird is when I've been working before with a plugged-in ethernet cable I've not had any problem getting to the share?

I can `PING` the other machine, but I can't access the share at ... `\\othermachine\c$`
I tried 'TRACERT` but that disappears off to the work network and eventually gets back to the local other machine after a few time-outs

Is there anyway to "force" the connection to stay local ?

**UPDATE:** the VPN is AEP SSL Tunnel

Answer (score 0):

The determining factor is your DEFAULT GATEWAY. Depending on the VPN client you are using, your ability to change the Default Gateway may be restricted whenever you are on the VPN. Most default configurations in CISCO, Juniper, or OpenVPN VPN's do not permit you to select anything OTHER than the remote gateway.

Comment: Weird, I've disconnected the AEP Tunnel, couldn't find any setting to change Default Gateway, reconnected and I can now ping the other local machine on IP6, and also access the share !!

Answer (score 0):

You want to [configure split tunneling](http://www.stevens.edu/itwiki/w/index.php/VPN_on_Windows_7_-_Split_Tunneling) between your VPN and home network.

1. Disconnect your VPN
2. Open your VPN connection properties
3. Click the 'Networking' tab
4. Select 'Internet Protocol Version 4' and click 'Properties'
5. Click "Advanced'
6. Uncheck 'Use default gateway on remote network'
7. Press 'OK' to close Advanced settings, 'OK' to close Internet Protocol Version 4 settings, and 'OK' to close connection properties.